# AFrame: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'sortObjects')

Tags: vite, aframe

I have a basic web application and I'm using Vite and AFrame. AFrame is installed as a node module, however I'm getting the error when I open the HTML page.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'sortObjects')
    at NewSystem.init (renderer.js:35:14)
    at module2.exports.System (system.js:42:8)
    at new NewSystem (system.js:147:43)
    at AScene.initSystem (a-scene.js:193:26)
    at module2.exports.registerSystem (system.js:155:51)
    at ./src/systems/renderer.js (renderer.js:11:25)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at ./src/systems/index.js (index.js:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at ./src/index.js (index.js:83:1)
```

Here's my `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="module" lang="ts" src="./script.ts"></script>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0px; overflow: hidden">
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <img id="snow" src="%BASE_URL%assets/pano/snow.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      </a-assets>
      <a-sky color="#6EBAA7"></a-sky>
      <a-sphere src="#snow" position="0 0 -5"></a-sphere>
      <a-sphere
        src="#snow"
        material="side: double; flatShading: false"
        position="0 0 -5"
        scale="50 50 50"
        animation__scale="property: scale; easing: easeInCubic; dur: 3000; from: 0 0 0; to: 50 50 50; autoplay: true; loop: true"
        animation__position="property: position; easing: easeInCubic; dur: 3000; from: 0 0 -5; to: 0 1.6 0; autoplay: true; loop: true"
      ></a-sphere>
      <a-entity camera look-controls wasd-controls position="0 1.6 0">
        <a-cursor
          id="cursor"
          color="white"
          rayOrigin="mouse"
          raycaster="objects: .clickable"
          w
          fuseTimeout="500"
          animation__click="property: scale; startEvents: click; easing: easeInCubic; dur: 150; from: 0.1 0.1 0.1; to: 1 1 1"
          animation__fusing="property: scale; startEvents: fusing; easing: easeInCubic; dur: 1500; from: 1 1 1; to: 0.1 0.1 0.1"
          animation__mouseleave="property: scale; startEvents: mouseleave; easing: easeInCubic; dur: 500; to: 1 1 1"
        ></a-cursor>
      </a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my `script.ts`

```js
import * as AFRAME from "aframe";

AFRAME.registerSystem("ball-scene-manager", {
  init: function () {
    this.ballScenes = document.querySelectorAll("[ball-scene]");
    this.currScene = undefined;
  },
});
```

Note that this works fine if I import AFrame from a CDN and write my code in Javascript directly within a script element inside of the html.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using AFrame from npm with Nuxt. I imported the npm AFrame module into a vue component using the following code:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
  if (process.client) {
    await import("aframe");
  }
</script>

<template>
  <a-scene>
    <a-box></a-box>
    <a-camera></a-camera>
  </a-scene>
</template>
```

This seems to have fixed the errors I was getting when using only vite.